# Read UnRead status in JSQMessagesViewController

Tags: ios, firebase, xcode7.3, jsqmessagesviewcontroller, swift2

I am using Firebase and working in Swift 2.3 and Xcode 7.3
I create chat app using *JSQMessagesViewController*
Chat working fine in live mode and in background mode

I want to set read, pending and unread status of messages in bubbles like WhatsApp and Messenger.

AnyOne help me????

Comment: Would you mind sharing or removing your question?

Comment: How did you do it? I'm stuck with this too....

Comment: Ya it would be great if you could shed any light on this matter.

Comment: Yeah @hunaintariq , for the message status it was fine, I just subclassed the JSQMessage and reloaded the data, but adding it to the view is more challenging, I just added a text on the bubble's bottom label, it appears that adding ImageViews will be more challenging...

Answer (score 1):

Yes i solve this issues,
Just add observer of ChilChanged, this observer will trigger when u changed any value in firebase

```
messageRef = channelRef!.child("messages")
messageRef.observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.ChildChanged, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
}) { (e) in
            print(e.localizedDescription)
        }
```

And when u get message just update your status like this, when u do this the above method will trigger on friends device and u can change your local object with respect to your Firebase DB

```
messageRef.observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
if messageData["status"] as String! == "Sent"{
                        let prntRef  = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("friends").child(self.chatId).child("messages").child(refKey)
                        prntRef.updateChildValues(["status":"Read"])
                    }
}) { (e) in
                print(e.localizedDescription)
                MBProgressHUD.hideHUDForView(self.view, animated: true)
        }
```